# Block validation failed for `core/pullquote` after adding theme support for editor-color-palette

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, block-editor

I added this function to my child theme's functions.php:

```php
/**
 * Adds support for custom editor color palette.
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/themes/theme-support/
 */
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'unht_setup_color_palette' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'unht_setup_color_palette' ) ) :
    function unht_setup_color_palette() {
        add_theme_support(
            'editor-color-palette',
            array(
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'test Green', 'mytheme' ),
                    'slug'  => 'test-green',
                    'color' => '#00693C',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'test Yellow', 'mytheme' ),
                    'slug'  => 'test-yellow',
                    'color' => '#FFB612',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'test Magenta', 'mytheme' ),
                    'slug'  => 'test-magenta',
                    'color' => '#B7295A',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'test Purple', 'mytheme' ),
                    'slug'  => 'test-purple',
                    'color' => '#752864',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'test Blue', 'mytheme' ),
                    'slug'  => 'test-blue',
                    'color' => '#0075B0',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'test Black', 'mytheme' ),
                    'slug'  => 'test-black',
                    'color' => '#000',
                ),
            )
        );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'unht_setup_color_palette' );
```

When I save and reload to try the colors, the Text Color pallete works, but when selecting a Main Color for pullquote blocks, I get the following error in the block: "This block contains unexpected or invalid content."

Paragraphs do not give me an error message. The console displays the following error several times:

```
blocks.min.js?ver=6.2.5:2 Block validation: Block validation failed for `core/pullquote` (Objectattributes: {value: {…}, citation: {…}, mainColor: {…}, customMainColor: {…}, textColor: {…}, …}category: "formatting"deprecated: (2) [{…}, {…}]description: "Give special visual emphasis to a quote from your text."edit: ƒ (t)icon: {src: {…}}name: "core/pullquote"save: ƒ (e)styles: (2) [{…}, {…}]supports: {align: Array(4)}title: "Pullquote"__proto__: Object).

Content generated by `save` function:

<figure class="wp-block-pullquote"><blockquote class="has-text-color has-test-yellow-color"><p>test</p></blockquote></figure>

Content retrieved from post body:

<figure class="wp-block-pullquote" style="border-color:#752864"><blockquote class="has-text-color has-test-yellow-color"><p>test</p></blockquote></figure>

blocks.min.js?ver=6.2.5:2 Block validation: Expected tag name `blockquote`, instead saw `figure`.
```

So it looks like it is automically adding a figure tag that messes up the validation. Is there a way to resolve this? Or is there another way to add custom colors to pullquotes? Thanks!

Comment: Does this issue happen for new blocks you've added after you made the change? Does using the `Resolve` button fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, it occurs with new pullquote blocks as well (using the Default style, Solid Color style gives no error). Resolve converts to HTML blocks, which isn't ideal, but I can work with if there's no solution.

Comment: You might want to add an issue at their GitHub tracker, too: https://github.com/wordpress/gutenberg/issues